What should be set in a python package to be a data exporter plugin for the PyMoDAQ software?
I want to add functionalities to the PyMoDAQ software by creating a python package. What has to be set for it to be recognized as such? In particular, I would like to add a particular exporter for the data saved as hdf5.
I've created a python package named pymodaq_plugins_nexus_exporter. In there I included an exporter object I expected to be recognized by the object factory. But it doesn't show up in the possibilities neither in the log. What am I missing?

Since you already use the right naming (ie: pymodaq_plugins_name), check the plugin_info.toml file that is use to "advertise" what your plugin is offering and how PyMoDAQ should import it.
The features section should look like :
[features]
instruments = false
extensions = false
models = false
h5exporters = true
scanners = false

so the h5exporters is our case if that's the only feature your plugin is offering.
